# from finite to $\sigma$-finite measure space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

This might be rather elementary. I have put it [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539116/9464) for a while without getting any answers.

Here is the **question**:
In the proof of the following theorem, would anyone explain how the general case (when $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ "$\sigma$-finite") can be deduced from the proved "finite" case?

[image]

Comment: Could you please include a link to the MSE question, so that people here can see it, or can answer over there?

Comment: @YemonChoi, Sure. I have put the link to the question accordingly.

Comment: The duplicate at MO was unduly migrated.

Answer (score 2):

The only point where the measures itself intervenes is in the definition of strong measurability, through simple convergence $\mu$-almost everywhere. A $\sigma$-finite measure is equivalent (in the sense has the same negligible sets) to a finite measure: partition $\Omega$ into countably many sets of finite $\mu$-measures, and define $d\nu=\rho\ d\mu$ where $\rho$ is positive, constant on each set of the partition, and decreases fast enough to make $\nu$ finite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see how the use of $\nu$ is relevant to showing the general case. Would you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an answer to the original question on MSE, which can be seen here: [How can this theorem about weakly measurable functions on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces be deduced from the finite measure space case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539116/from-finite-to-sigma-finite-measure-space/1542206#1542206). I have left it un-copied since it's not research-level.