# In a proof of "weakly measurable implies measurable"

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, locally-convex-spaces

This is a follow-up question to the following ones:

- [How can this theorem about weakly measurable functions on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces be deduced from the finite measure space case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539116/9464)
- [properties of a separable metrizable locally convex space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1543026/9464)

I'm reading the proof the following theorem:

> If $X$ is a separable, metrizable locally convex space, $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $f:\Omega\to X$ is weakly measurable, then $f$ is strongly measurable.

The first part of the proof shows that $f$ is measurable:

> We can restrict ourselves to the case of finite measures. We prove first that $f$ is measurable. To do this it suffices to show that 
>   $$
> f^{-1}(x+V)\in\Sigma
> $$
>   whenever $x\in X$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ and a barrel.  Replacing $f$ by $f-x$, we may also assume that $x=0$. Choose points $y_n\in X\setminus V$, and open convex neighborhoods $V_n$ of $0$ so that
>   $$
> X\setminus V=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(y_n+V_n).
> $$
>   Choose next functional $\varphi_n\in X^*$ such that
>   $$
> \Re\varphi_n(y_n+v_n)>\Re\varphi_n(v)\tag{*}
> $$
>   whenever $v_n\in V_n$ and $v\in V$. ($\color{red}{Question:}$ Why $\varphi_n$ exists? Are we using some separation theorem here?) Then the set
>   $$
> f^{-1}(x+V)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{\omega\in\Omega:\Re \varphi_n(f(\omega))\leq\sup_{v\in V}|\varphi_n(v)|\}\tag{**}
> $$ 
>   is a countable intersection of sets in $\Sigma$. ($\color{red}{Question:}$ <s>I'm quite sure that $\Re f(\omega)$ is a typo, which might be $\Re \varphi_n(f(\omega))$.</s> Could anyone explain how to get (**)? <s>I don't see it has anything to do with (*).</s> )

Could somebody help me with the questions indicated in the proof?

Also, I'm wondering if anyone could come up with a cited reference for the proof of this theorem.

---

[Updated:] One more typo fixed. It is quite clear now that one can *use* (*) to show (**).